# Redirecting URL paths with HAProxy and retaining Query Strings

Tags: haproxy

We have a URL map file loaded into HAProxy using the following:

```
http-request redirect location %[capture.req.uri,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 301 if { capture.req.uri,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found }
```

An example of a line in the map file would be:

```
/shop-by-category /products
```

This redirect works as expected.  The only issue I'm experiencing is when a query string is passed with the /shop-by-category path.  E.g:

```
/shop-by-category?testingquerystring=test
```

This will not redirect.

I've tried adding what I believe to be the HAProxy query variable to the redirect map like:

```
/shop-by-category&%[query] /parts&%[query]
```

But HAProxy does not appear to recognise this in the map file.  Is there any way I can have HAProxy dynamically recognise the query string and also pass it through when it redirects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that you can't use fetches inside a map file -- it's static, and loaded at startup, so nothing could be interpolated.

[`capture.req.uri`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-capture.req.uri) refers to URI in the RFC sense:

> `capture.req.uri : string`
>
> This extracts the request's URI, which starts at the first slash and ends
>   before the first space in the request (without the host part). Unlike "`path`"
>   and "`url`", it can be used in both request and response because it's
>   allocated.

...so it sounds like you should be using the [`path`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-path) fetch for matching and the [`query`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-query) fetch in the rewrite, if it is set.

> `path : string`
>
> This extracts the request's URL path, which starts at the first slash and
>   ends before the question mark (without the host part).
>
> `query : string`
>
> This extracts the request's query string, which starts after the first
>   question mark. If no question mark is present, this fetch returns nothing. If
>   a question mark is present but nothing follows, it returns an empty string.
>   This means it's possible to easily know whether a query string is present
>   using the "found" matching method. This fetch is the complement of "path"
>   which stops before the question mark.

Two lines for match and rewrite are then required.

First, a rewrite if the query string is present:

```
http-request redirect location %[path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)]?%[query] code 301 if { path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found } { query -m found }
```

Then, a rewrite if the query string is absent:

```
http-request redirect location %[path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 301 if { path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found } ! { query -m found }
```

Your map file would be paths only.

Comment: That worked perfectly and makes sense, I assumed the map file that would be loaded in with the variables and they'd continue to be read that way.  Thanks a lot.